# Какие плагины категорические нельзя отключать в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-sdk

Какие плагины категорические нельзя отключать в Android Studio?
Иначе придется удалять студию и все заново ставить!
Причем самому по пути искать остатки:
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
C:\Users\ **NameUser**\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3

Answer (score -1):

- Smali Support
- Gradle
- Groovy
- Kotlin
- Properties
- JUnit
- IntelliLang
- Toml
- WebP Support

Нельзя отключать плагины с упоминанием Android и Android Material.
Все остальные можно выключить, но тогда будет урезан функционал.